# Is it possible to use Factory Girl to update an already instanced factory?

Tags: ruby, factory-bot, qabstracttablemodel

I am trying to streamline our cukes trying to leverage the wonderful factories built into our system for unit tests.

I am setting up a `@bread ||= FactoryGirl.create(:bread)` in a background step.

Throughout that feature, I want to add a trait which would be called `@bread ||= FactoryGirl.create(:bread, :organic)` if the background step did not exist.

Since `@bread` already exists, is there a way for me to 'update' it with the trait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (I haven't tested this)

```
@bread.update(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:bread, :organic)
```

Comment: should I do a `@bred.reload`?

Comment: only it didn't trigger the creation of the ingredients on a `after :create do`